# Rails 4 Update Nested Attributes and avoid Duplicate Information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I create an application whit a nested form.

In my Model for Bur_audit.

```
    class BurAudit < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :personal_adits, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :public_entity
    belongs_to :taking
    belongs_to :area
    before_create :validar_entidad_area_reca
    after_save :llena_tabla_per_buro_audit
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :personal_adits, allow_destroy: true 

    QUINCENA = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"]
    CALENDARIO = ((yr=Date.current.year)-7..yr).to_a

    include InformixQueryHelper

    def validar_entidad_area_reca
        entidad = self.public_entity_id
        puts entidad
        self.entidad_publica = entidad
        e = PublicEntity.find_by "entidad_publica = " + entidad.to_s  
        id = e.id
        self.public_entity_id = id

        area = self.area_id
        puts area
        self.departamento = area
        a = Area.find_by "area = " + area.to_s  
        id = a.id
        self.area_id = id

        reca = self.taking_id
        puts reca
        self.recaudacion = reca
        r = Taking.find_by "recaudacion = " + reca.to_s  
        id = r.id
        self.taking_id = id 
    end
    def llena_tabla_per_buro_audit
        id = self.id
        dependencia = self.entidad_publica
        area = self.departamento
        recaudacion = self.recaudacion
        calendario = self.calendario
        quincena = self.quincena
        bur_audit_empleado_horario(dependencia,area,recaudacion,id, calendario, quincena)
    end

end
```

before_safe I have to make a connection to informix Server and run a query to get the information I need in my relation with Personal Adits.

The information save perfectly but when I do an update the attibutes from Personal Adits Duplicate my records on the table.

in my controller im trying this

```
    # encoding: utf-8
class BurAuditsController < ApplicationController
  include InformixQueryHelper

  before_action :set_bur_audit, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html, :xml, :json, :pdf, :xls, :csv

  def index
    @bur_audits = BurAudit.all
    respond_with(@bur_audits)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@bur_audit)
  end

  def new
    @bur_audit = BurAudit.new
    respond_with(@bur_audit)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @bur_audit = BurAudit.new(bur_audit_params)
    @bur_audit.save
    respond_with(@bur_audit)
  end
def update
    @bur_audit.update(update_bur_audit_params)
    respond_with(@bur_audit)
  end

  def destroy
    @bur_audit.destroy
    respond_with(@bur_audit)
  end

  def for_auditoria_burocrata
    puts("preparandose para lanzar")
    bur_audit_empleado_horario(params[:dependencia], params[:area], params[:recaudacion])
    render json: @bur_empleado
  end

  def for_entidad_area_id

    sql = "select a.id, a.description
            from areas  a
            where a.status = 'A'
            and a.entidad_publica = '#{params[:public_entity_id]}'
            and a.fecha_efectiva in (select max(fecha_efectiva)
                                  from areas
                                  where a.area = area)
            order by description"
    @area = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows(sql)
    @area.map{|id,description|}
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json  { render :json => @area }
    end  
  end
  private
    def set_bur_audit
      @bur_audit = BurAudit.find(params[:id])
    end

    def bur_audit_params
      params.require(:bur_audit).permit(:id, :titulo, :public_entity_id, :entidad_publica, :area_id, :departamento, :taking_id, :recaudacion, :quincena, :calendario , personal_adits_attributes:[:id, :building_id, :labora_true, :absence_cause_id, :area_funcional, :tiempo_area, :per_cargo, :escolaridad, :cumple_perfil, :reg_asistencia, :horario, :viaja, :frecuencia, :jefe_directo, :funsiones, :regularizado, :observaciones, :sueldo, :_destroy])
    end

    def update_bur_audit_params
      params.require(:bur_audit).permit(personal_adits_attributes:[:id, :bur_audit_id ,:building_id,:labora_true,:absence_cause_id,:area_funcional,:tiempo_area,:per_cargo,:escolaridad,:cumple_perfil,:reg_asistencia,:horario,:viaja,:frecuencia,:jefe_directo,:funsiones,:regularizado,:observaciones,:sueldo, :_destroy])
    end
```

Someone know a way to avoid the duplication of my information.

Comment: when you look at the development.log does it show an INSERT sql statements for the update action?

Comment: yes this is what I find 
  ^[[1m^[[35mSQL (1.6ms)^[[0m  INSERT INTO "personal_adits" ("bur_audit_id", "created_at", "horario", "no_empleado", "nombre", "puesto_desc", "rel_pago", "reloj", "status_hor", "status_reloj", "sueldo", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"  [["bur_audit_id", 89], ["created_at", "2015-09-30 21:29:00.035363"], ["horario", "8:00-16:00 L-V"], ["no_empleado", 4573], ["nombre", "MORONES GONZALEZ JOSE MANUEL"], ["puesto_desc", "ASESOR TECNICO"], ["rel_pago", "181320401001001  "], etc.

Comment: There is nothing obvious I can see in the code you have posted here. Can you post the information about the request params that appears at the start of the action in the log file? The line that starts: INFO -- : Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",...

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XWNmgRoLAyRYnHsIZPbnuk4ip589ozqNDDiLCUSQIMc=", "button"=>"", "bur_audit"=>{"titulo"=>"Prueba de Duplicidad", "public_entity_id"=>"204", "area_id"=>"3011000005001", "taking_id"=>"14", "calendario"=>"2015", "quincena"=>"16", "personal_adits_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"building_id"=>"", "labora_true"=>"SI", "absence_cause_id"=>"", "area_funcional"=>"", "tiempo_area"=>"", "per_cargo"=>"", "escolaridad"=>"", "cumple_perfil"=>"", "reg_asistencia"=>"", "horario"=>"8:00-16:00 L-V", "viaja"=>"", "frecuencia"=>"", "jefe_directo"=>"", "funsiones"=>"", etc

Answer (score 0):

It appears from the comments that the parameters being passed in by the POST action are causing the duplicate record to be created. The params mentioned in the comment are:

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"XWNmgRoLAyRYnHsIZPbnuk4ip589ozqNDDiLCUSQIMc=",
>   "button"=>"", "bur_audit"=>{"titulo"=>"Prueba de Duplicidad",
>   "public_entity_id"=>"204", "area_id"=>"3011000005001",
>   "taking_id"=>"14", "calendario"=>"2015", "quincena"=>"16",
>   **"personal_adits_attributes"=>{"0"=>**{"building_id"=>"",
>   "labora_true"=>"SI", "absence_cause_id"=>"", "area_funcional"=>"",
>   "tiempo_area"=>"", "per_cargo"=>"", "escolaridad"=>"",
>   "cumple_perfil"=>"", "reg_asistencia"=>"", "horario"=>"8:00-16:00
>   L-V", "viaja"=>"", "frecuencia"=>"", "jefe_directo"=>"",
>   "funsiones"=>"", etc

Notice the part that starts `"personal_adits_attributes"=>{"0"=>`. This indicates to me that an array of personal_adits fields can be passed in. It is likely that the continuation shows `"1"=>` later in the block.

My assumption is that this information being posted by the form has multiple personal_adits nested in it, created manually by the user (for example clicking a "add personal adit" button). There is no sign of the personal_adit being instantiated in the **bur_audits_controller** **new** action or in the initialization of the **BurAudit** model, so I am guessing it is a manual action that is creating the multiple items.

Alternatively, the **bur_audit/_form.html.erb** file is instantiating multiple personal_adit instances prior to showing the nested form.

To finally validate, add the following just before the form tag for @bur audit in the form partial.

I expect this will be a number greater than one, which will show that the personal_adit list is already created. If it is 0 or 1 then dig into the nested forms to see when they are created. Potentially there is a UI activity that is effectively causing multiple nested personal_adit forms to be created. For example a `$(document).on('click'...` being registered twice and therefore leading to double events for a single user action.

Feel free to edit this answer or the original question with additional information if it helps.

Comment: Its right I. First create de bur_audit record then after_save I make a conection to external DB to get the information in order to fill the table Personal_adits. then when I have to edit the Bur_audit use a partial with all the fields in my nested table personal_adits. have and idea how to fix it?

Comment: The second time you show the bur_audit form, does it have an :id parameter in it? If not, it may try to create again.

Comment: in my bur_audit_form I have hidden the field id, and also have the id parameter hidden in my partial when i call  the nested fields of personal_adits.

Comment: If you look at the form in the browser console, does it show the id field has a value? It doesn't look like the id is being passed in the submitted parameters in the details you provided.

Comment: in my form bur_audit have and id = 91 and the first record of my nested file have and id = 1606
when i push the save button the parameters are

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"es4O2tQtU1yKvtHFMI4lp6EhqSRfiLLRRbDQrvBX4lc=", "button"=>"", "bur_audit"=>{"titulo"=>"Prueba de Duplicidad", "public_entity_id"=>"204", "area_id"=>"3011000005001", "taking_id"=>"14", "calendario"=>"2015", "quincena"=>"16", "personal_adits_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"building_id"=>"", "labora_true"=>"SI", "absence_cause_id"=>"COMISION", "area_funcional"=>"", "tiempo_area"=>"", "per_cargo"=>"", "escolaridad"=>"", "cumple_perfil"=>"", "reg_asistencia"=>"", "horario"=>"8:00-16:00 L-V", "observaciones"=>"", "id"=>"1606"}

Comment: I don't see "id"=>"91" in the parameters you pasted. Maybe your comment was truncated, or maybe the id isn't being posted.

Comment: have you an email, gmail hangout to talk about haw to solve?